# Implementing custom loss function in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, gridsearchcv

I want to implement a custom loss function in scikit learn. I use the following code snippet:

```
def my_custom_loss_func(y_true,y_pred):
   diff3=max((abs(y_true-y_pred))*y_true)
   return diff3

score=make_scorer(my_custom_loss_func,greater_ is_better=False)
clf=RandomForestRegressor()
mnn= GridSearchCV(clf,score)
knn = mnn.fit(feam,labm)
```

What should be the arguments passed into `my_custom_loss_func`? My label matrix is called `labm`. I want to calculate the difference between the actual and the predicted output (by the model ) multiplied by the true output. If I use `labm` in place of `y_true`, what should I use in place of `y_pred`?

Answer (score 26):

Okay, there's 3 things going on here:

1) there is a loss function while training used to tune your models parameters

2) there is a scoring function which is used to judge the quality of your model

3) there is hyper-parameter tuning which uses a scoring function to optimize your hyperparameters.

So... if you are trying to tune hyperparameters, then you are on the right track in defining a "loss fxn" for that purpose. If, however, you are trying to tune your whole model to perform well on, lets say, a recall test - then you need a recall optimizer to be part of the training process. It's tricky, but you can do it...

1) Open up your classifier. Let's use an RFC for example: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html

2) click [source]

3) See how it's inheriting from ForestClassifier? Right there in the class definition. Click that word to jump to it's parent definition.

4) See how this new object is inheriting from ClassifierMixin? Click that.

5) See how the bottom of that ClassifierMixin class says this?

```
from .metrics import accuracy_score
return accuracy_score(y, self.predict(X), sample_weight=sample_weight)
```

That's your model being trained on accuracy. You need to inject at this point if you want to train your model to be a "recall model" or a "precision model" or whatever model. This accuracy metric is baked into SKlearn. Some day, a better man than I will make this a parameter which models accept, however in the mean time, you gotta go into your sklearn installation, and tweak this accuracy_score to be whatever you want.

Best of luck!

Comment: is this still true today?

Comment: That line in `ClassifierMixin` is defining the `score` method, which is used in parts 2&3 of your top list, but _is not used_ for part 1, the actual optimization that happens in the `fit` method of the model itself.  That optimization depends on the model type, but generally is a better and more nuanced loss function than accuracy.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for make_scorer goes like this:

```
sklearn.metrics.make_scorer(score_func, greater_is_better=True, needs_proba=False, 
needs_threshold=False, **kwargs)
```

So, it dosen't need you to pass arguments while calling the function.
Is this what you were asking?

Comment: I mean while defining the fucnction, my_custom_func_loss, ( the first line of my code), I need to pass arguments right? Without arguments, how can I write the body of the function? I was asking about those arguments. Here I passed y_true and y_pred.

Comment: yea! you only need those 2 arguments. However, if you want to pass some additional arguments you could do something like this: score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs) where **kwargs are the extra parameters that you'd want to pass

Comment: I mean by default y will be assigned the label matrix and y_pred the predicted values of the model? don’t I need to define those values in the code? I have seen people writing truths, preds. So can we write anything as the argument and scikit learn will be able to make out? It seems a bit weird.

Comment: See, If you pass them in the order it would take the arguments as you have defined within the function. ex: Let's suppose we have a function like this costFunc(y, y_pred). Now, if you pass values like costFunc(labels, predictions) then labels would be passed to y and predictions would be passed to y_pred. However, you could do an alternative like this: costFunc(y_pred = predictions, y = labels). As you can see the order is no longer required if you mention the name and pass.

Comment: I mean by default scikit learn will assume the first argument is the true label and the second argument corresponds to the predicted model output? If i write only y and y_pred, without explicitly mentioning anywhere what is y and what is y_pred, it will still work?

Comment: yes, but the order should not be altered i.e it should be the same as your function

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of your my_custom_func_loss, does not have any connection with your true labels, which is `labm`. You can keep the way as it now.

Internally GridSearchCV will call the scoring function hence your true labels does not conflict there. `y_pred` would be the predicted values, generated from the model's output. `y_true` will be assigned with the values of `labm`.